# How to add two number fetched from SharedPreferences in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, sharedpreferences

I was trying to add two numbers say `point1` and `point2`. These points are stored in SharedPreferences . 
I have fetched the points using a function `Future<int> fetchPoints` which is in below.
Then I called this from another function

**fetchPoints:**

`Future<int> fetchFromSps(String field) async {
    SharedPreferences sp = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return sp.getInt(field);
  }`

**GetPoints:**

```
Future<void> setPoints() async{
    int _newPoints=await ((await fetchFromSps('point1'))+(await fetchFromSps('point2')));
    setState(() {
      _totalPoints=_newPoints.toString();
    });
  }
```

**setInSharedPreference:**

```
void setInSharedPreference() async{
    SharedPreferences prefs=await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setInt('point1', 0);
    prefs.setInt('point2',0);
}
```

The function setInSharedPreference is in another dart file,which contains main function

I need to add two points which is named `'point1` and `'point2'` from shared preference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just call them from any method like this sample:

```
  fetchTwoPoints() async {
     final point1 = await fetchFromSps("point1");
     final point2 = await fetchFromSps("point2");
      setState(() {
         _totalPoints= (point1 + point2).toString();
       });
  }
```

Update your `setInSharedPreference` method because you are using async you need to wait to store the data.

```
Future<void> setInSharedPreference() async{
    SharedPreferences prefs=await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setInt('point1', 0);
    await prefs.setInt('point2',0);
}
```

Comment: i want to add them also. How to do that?

Comment: point1+point2 is giving an error( `NoSuchMethodError: The method '+' was called on null.`)

Comment: did you store the values before? otherwise if you use sp.getInt(field) it will return null . could you add the code?

Comment: do you mean sharedpreference?

Comment: yes, if you want to get the points , you need to save the points before, otherwise it will return null